# Update the values of a data table automatically in JavaScript using HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a pie chart and in the method of defining data, it is required a `DataTable`. Now, I'm trying to make it so the user can write their own input and then this input will be placed on the rows.

For example, on the div with `id="ativo1"` I have a value set to `TSLA`. However, I'd like to make this dynamic so that the user can delete this and input a new value which will then change the name of the slice on the pie chart. I'm trying to use `onchange` and `addEventListener` to detect these changes, but with no success.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>

        <div class="table">
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Ativo </div>
                <div class="td">Quota % </div>
                <div class="td">Perda Potencial % </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="TSLA" class="stock" id="ativo1"
                        onchange="changeFunction(this.value);" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota1" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda1" /> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="AAPL" class="stock" id="ativo2" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota2" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda2" /> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="MSFT" class="stock" id="ativo3" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota3" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda3" /> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="EURUSD" class="stock" id="ativo4" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota4" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda4" /> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td"><input type="text" size="5" value="BITCOIN" class="stock" id="ativo5" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="20" value="20" class="quota" id="quota5" /> </div>
                <div class="td"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="perda" id="perda5" /></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>


</body>
<script>
    let perda = 0;
    document.querySelector(".table").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        const tgt = e.target;
        if (tgt.classList.contains("perda")) {
            perda = tgt.closest(".tr").querySelector(".quota").value = 20 - (tgt.value * 0.20);
            // quota * perda potencial; var = quota * +- perda potencial / 100
            //quota - var;
            //let var = perda/risco potencial
            console.log(20 - perda)

            //perda += perda;  //isto teria que atualizar sempre que a perda potencial % aumenta ou diminui. Neste momento, apenas faz a soma, nao retira o valor quando perda potencial % diminui e a quota aumenta
        }

    })
</script>
<script>
    //add event listener here maybe?
    function changeFunction(val) {
        ativoVar1.value = document.getElementById("ativo1").value;
    }

    let ativoVar1 = document.getElementById("ativo1").value;



    // addEventListener e innerHTML;
    let ativoVar2 = document.getElementById("ativo2").value; // procurar nos docs sobre refreshChartPie (função)
    let ativoVar3 = document.getElementById("ativo3").value;
    let ativoVar4 = document.getElementById("ativo4").value;
    let ativoVar5 = document.getElementById("ativo5").value;

    let quotaVar1 = document.querySelector(".quota").value;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Ativo');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quota');
        data.addRows([
            [ativoVar1, 20], // passar metodo numerico 
            [ativoVar2, 20],
            [ativoVar3, 20],
            [ativoVar4, 20],
            [ativoVar5, 20],
            ['Perda', 1]
        ]);
        var options = {
            title: 'Calculadora'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }


</script>


<style>
    .td {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 120px;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: I would convert to a form replacing those div's for inputs and add a form submit button to update the chart.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so it updates automatically without a submit button

Comment: It's almost always better to combine script elements into a single one rather than breaking them up. Every time the HTML parser hits `<script>`, it has to switch from HTML parsing to JavaScript parsing. Also, no tags except `body` and `head` should show up between `<html>` and `</html>`. Neither of these are likely related to your issue, but may come up if you attempt to validate your HTML or run your site through something like Google's Lighthouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is optmization to do here so take this example with a grain of salt.
I would add the `onchange="changeFunction()"` to every input you want to fire updates on the chart:

```
function changeFunction() {
  drawChart();
}
```

The `drawChart()` would call `getValues()` to get values from all inputs and redraw the chart each time an input is changed:

```
function getValues() {
  var data = {};

  var ativos = document.querySelectorAll(".stock");
  var quotas = document.querySelectorAll(".quota");

  //console.log(ativos);
  //console.log(quotas);

  for (let i = 0; i < ativos.length; i++) {
    //console.log(quotas[i].value);
    data[ativos[i].value] = quotas[i].value;
  }

  //console.log(data);
  return data;
}

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Ativo');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Quota');

  var dataSet = getValues();

  //console.log(dataSet);

  for (let key in dataSet) {
    data.addRow([key, parseInt(dataSet[key])]);
  }

  var options = {
    title: 'Calculadora'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58w6pxLt/1/)